# Content Type Upgrade / Feature Upgrade / Solution Upgrade in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, content-type, feature-upgrade

I have a SharePoint 2013 site in Multi Tenant mode. For every tenant, I have a Content Type Hub along with a Root Site, Tenant Admin and a Document Center site collections. In the Content Type Hub, I have deployed Site Columns and Content Types through features in Visual Studio (using declarative approach). The content types are published using feature receivers. Now, in future, if I have to update my content types and site columns, what would be the best approach? I am thinking of using Content Type Upgrade / Feature Upgrade / Solution Upgrade. But there is no clear road map for doing this in SharePoint 2013 in a step-by-step manner. Most of the articles seem to be for 2010 and written 5 to 6 years ago. So I am not sure about their validity for SharePoint 2013. Also, some of them are also contradicting with each other. Can anyone please suggest and if possible, provide some good articles or videos which have step-by-step information on this?

PS: Please note that the changes would involve Adding New Columns, Updating Existing Columns, Removing Existing Columns, Adding/Updating/Removing Event Receivers.

Comment: If you use server side code it is exactly the same for 2010 and 2013 regarding feature upgrade patterns

Comment: Can you please provide a good article/blog/forum/tutorial which explains it step-by-step for SharePoint 2013?

Comment: Just follow Chris O'Brien's guide for 2010.. http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2010/06/feature-upgrade-part-1-fundamentals.html

Comment: As I said earlier, this was written way back in 2010. I am not sure if it still holds good for SharePoint 2013. I had already seen this before.

Comment: And, as I said before; it is still valid

Comment: I am interested in knowing about Content Type Upgrade in particular, more than Feature / Solution Upgrade. I couldn't find anything on Content Type Upgrade.